# How to stop repeated Ajax calls in React class?

Tags: reactjs, ajax, repeat

I inherited an old version of React that starts like this:

```
var rc = React.createClass({

 render() {

      // Ajax code, here, is called repeatedly for some reason

      return {
           ...
      }
 }
})
```

I'm stuck with this old code architecture, and I could not import React component. I tried to make an Ajax call to the server side using jQuery and saw the expected result returned in the console. I had tried using React to make the Ajax call but no result was returned, perhaps due to the lack of the React Component.  That's why I turned to jQuery instead.

The problem is that, for whatever reason, the Ajax was called repeatedly, non-stop, for both React & jQuery methods (the Ajax code was not inside any loop). I didn't have this Ajax repeating issue at home when I used a recent version of React. At work, I had to work with the above code implemented by a previous developer.  How can I stop the Ajax from making repeated calls, considering the above code architecture that I am in ?  I only need to make one Ajax call.  Any idea ?  Thanks!

Comment: You should put the call inside the `componentDidMount` method, so it's only called once, after the component mounts. And you should learn React too, knowing how state management works and what the lifecycles methods are is gonna be needed, or this will just be the start of your headaches

Comment: You should put your ajax code in the `componentDidMount`, or `componentDidUpdate`. `render` is called initially and everytime react rerenders the component, resulting in the repeated calls you are seeing. `componentDidMount` will fire once, when the component first mounts and `componentDidUpdate` will fire once for each rerender but allows for a comparison of current and previous state / props.

Comment: Thanks Jacob & Jayce, yes, I agree.  As stated above, I didn't have this issue using a recent version of React for my personal work at home, and yes, I did put my ajax call inside "componentDidMount" and it worked great.  The above code concern was from my work place and I'm stuck in that code architecture.  I mean I was not able to import React component to carry out ajax.  "componentDidMount" does not work without importing React component first but this is a rather old code which doesn't accept importing React component.  What would be a work-around solution for this ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be doing state update in render or after fetching data from **API's**.
Here is what might help you.

```
  var rc = React.createClass({

componentDidMount(){
          // Write AJAX Code here
          }

     render() {
          //Avoid any state update here
          return {
               ...
          }
        }
    })
```